# Maple says integral is zero for all integers, but it isn't for 1.

Tags: maple

```
> assume(n::'integer'):
> int(exp(n * x * I) * cos(x), x = 0 .. 2 * Pi);
                               0
```

But if we substitute n=1 by hand:

```
> int(exp(x * I) * cos(x), x = 0 .. 2 * Pi);
                               Pi
```

How do I get Maple to tell me which integral values of $n$ make the integral non-zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `allsolutions` option to the `int` command can sometimes handle this kind of special case.

But the integrand may have to be rewritten to a form in which `int` recognizes the issue.

```
assume(n::'integer'):

igrand := simplify(evalc(exp(n*x*I)*cos(x)));

    igrand := cos(x) (sin(n~ x) I + cos(n~ x))

int(igrand, x = 0 .. 2 * Pi, allsolutions);

        { Pi        Or(n~ = -1, n~ = 1)
        {
        { 0              otherwise
```

The last result above is a piecewise construct.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove this hypotesis:

> assume(n::'integer'):

Maple will answer $$\dfrac{In(1-e^{2In\pi})}{n^2-1}$$ which shows that $n=\pm 1$ are special values.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular one, we can try this:

> `seq(int(exp(n * x * I) * cos(x), x = 0 .. 2 * Pi) ,n=1..10);`
> `Pi, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0`

Comment: Thanks, and that does help.  However, it misses that n=-1 is also non zero.  If you remove the assumption, you get a resulting formula with $n^2-1$ in the denominator and a single zero in the numerator, so can see that $n=\pm 1$ are the only possibilities.  However, if I didn't know that the maple answer was wrong, I wouldn't think to look for values of $n$ where it's non-zero.

Comment: Is I supposed to be $i=\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: Yes Maple code for $\sqrt{-1}$ is `I`.